# Add timeout to procedure waiting for Internet Explorer

Tags: vbscript

I call this sub in my VBScript, which waits for Internet Explorer to finish loading before moving onto the next line:

```
Sub Wait
   Do While objIE.ReadyState < 4 Or objIE.Busy
      WScript.Sleep 200
   Loop
End Sub
```

Which works fine. However, occasionally when there is Internet connectivity problems, the web page will get stuck in the loading stage and the script will therefore continue to wait.

**So my question is:**
Can I set a timeout so that when i call this sub, it waits for a specified time, e.g. 5 minutes, before quitting the script?

Comment: You can add a timer var and check for a set interval in the loop. If the threshold is reached, break the loop and move on?

Comment: Rather than waiting for some fix duration why don't you use vbscript to check whether connection is present or not? Here is the exapmle -http://www.visualbasicscript.com/VBScript-to-check-network-connection-m1700.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a time limit to your procedure like this:

```
Sub Wait
   limit = DateAdd("n", 5, Now)
   Do While (objIE.ReadyState < 4 Or objIE.Busy) And Now < limit
      WScript.Sleep 200
   Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

```
    oIE.Visible = True
    oIE.navigate ("http://technopedia.com")



Do While oIE.Busy Or oIE.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop  


                              <<<<< OR >>>>>>

Do While oIE.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop
```

Any other suggestions ??